# Why ajax HTTP POST gets an empty response from server?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a POST request in ajax  in this way:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://192.168.1.140/',
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data, success, failure) {
                    alert("Error:" + failure);
                }
            });
```

The server I have at that IP only do this:

```
<?php
echo "test"
?>
```

In the alert I only get the word 'Error' from the error function and nothing else from the parameters. I don't know where is the problem. I want it to display in the alert the word 'test' that the servers sends. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show the `console.log()` that error throw?  use the first param `data` instead failure.

Comment: Try: `contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"` You are receiving plain text,not json.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because you're telling jQuery ajax that this request will return a json response but you just return plain text.

I'm not sure why your errorThrown is blank as it should show parse error.
You can just have `alert("Error:" + data.responseText);` to alert the result.

To avoid the error you can echo json in your php script `echo '{"test":true}'`
or remove the `dataType: "json",` in your request.